# Показать график Tradingview на своей странице

Tags: веб-программирование, iframe, tradingview

Знаю, что у трейдингвью есть свои библиотеки для интеграции графиков в свою платформу.
А можно ли каким-то образом подгружать и индикаторы которые есть на моем графике в аккаунте трейдингвью? Или загружать в фрейме?

Comment: Ответ: Нельзя. Индикаторы рендерит сервер. На экране лишь результат индикатора. Для просмотра индикатора нужен аккаунт. Если не ошибаюсь, один аккаунт одновременно может смотреть только 6 графиков. Если делать iframe, то во-первых, нужно будет авторизовывать человека (а это чревато потерей аккаунта) либо ему как-то в браузер добавить свои кукисы (что практически невозможно), во-вторых, все что пользователь будет делать на графике, будут видеть все остальные пользователи, получать общие уведомления и проч. Плюс ко всему количество сессий тоже ограничено, даже на самом дорогом тарифе не больше 5

Comment: Единственный возможный вариант - это транслировать экран. Это довольно просто, но не динамично

Comment: @DiD т.е. т.е. транслировать экран это типа запустить ютуб трансляцию? Это не очень вариант.

Comment: Ну во всех других случаях придется график и индикаторы программировать самостоятельно